# mysite creation failed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, mysite

I deleted my site on Sp 2010 and when I click MyContent sharepoint try to create a new MySite for me but get error like

```
There has been an error creating the personal site. Contact your site administrator for more information
```

When i check event viewer in server i see below error. What is Azure.thmx file? How can fix this problem any idea ?

Thanks

```
My Site creation failure for user 'DOMAIN\MyUSername' for site url 'http://mysite.xxx.com.tr/personal/MyUsername'. 

The exception was: Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PersonalSiteCreateException: A failure was encountered while attempting to create the site. 
---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Failed to instantiate file "Azure.thmx" from module "OOBThemes": Source path "lists\themes\Azure.thmx" not found. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81070587): <nativehr>0x81070587</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Failed to instantiate file "Azure.thmx" from module "OOBThemes": Source path "lists\themes\Azure.thmx" not found.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SscCreateSite(Guid gApplicationId, String bstrUrl, String bstrServerRelativeUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SscCreateSite(Guid gApplicationId, String bstrUrl, String bstrServerRelativeUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SscCreateSite(Guid gApplicationId, String bstrUrl, String bstrServerRelativeUrl, Int32 lZone, Guid gSiteId, Guid gDatabaseId, String bstrDatabaseServer, String bstrDatabaseName, String bstrDatabaseUsername, String bstrDatabasePassword, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String bstrOwnerLogin, String bstrOwnerUserKey, String bstrOwnerName, String bstrOwnerEmail, String bstrSecondaryContactLogin, String bstrSecondaryContactUserKey, String bstrSecondaryContactName, String bstrSecondaryContactEmail, Boolean bADAccountMode, Boolean bHostHeaderIsSiteName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Add(SPContentDatabase database, SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription, String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String secondaryContactLogin, String secondaryContactName, String secondaryContactEmail, String quotaTemplate, String sscRootWebUrl, Boolean useHostHeaderAsSiteName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.SelfServiceCreateSite(String siteUrl, String title, String description, UInt32 nLCID, String webTemplate, String ownerLogin, String ownerName, String ownerEmail, String contactLogin, String contactName, String contactEmail, String quotaTemplate, SPSiteSubscription siteSubscription)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateSite>b__0()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateSite>b__0()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.<>c__DisplayClass4.<RunWithElevatedPrivileges>b__2()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.CreateSite(String strRequestUrl, Boolean bCollision, Int32 lcid).
```

Comment: I already solve problem copy Azure.thmx file from another server to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\Lists\themes folder in my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy Azure.thmx file from another server to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\Lists\themes folder in your server. :)